# Drop ALL triggers from Postgres DB?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Is there any way to drop ALL triggers from ALL tables in Postgres? I know there's a pg_trigger table I could look at, but it doesn't look like it contains enough information for me to decipher which triggers I have added to my tables.

It also looks like Foreign Key constraints show up in the pg_trigger table, which I DO NOT want to drop. I just want to drop the user created trigger from my tables and keep the FKs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks, James.

The function from [Drop ALL triggers from Postgres DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093214/drop-all-triggers-from-postgres-db/3454172#3454172) strips only the occurrence from the first table and leaves the triggers with the same name in other tables. Here is the fixed function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION strip_all_triggers() RETURNS text AS $$ DECLARE
    triggNameRecord RECORD;
    triggTableRecord RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR triggNameRecord IN select distinct(trigger_name) from information_schema.triggers where trigger_schema = 'public' LOOP
        FOR triggTableRecord IN SELECT distinct(event_object_table) from information_schema.triggers where trigger_name = triggNameRecord.trigger_name LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE 'Dropping trigger: % on table: %', triggNameRecord.trigger_name, triggTableRecord.event_object_table;
            EXECUTE 'DROP TRIGGER ' || triggNameRecord.trigger_name || ' ON ' || triggTableRecord.event_object_table || ';';
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN 'done';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;

select strip_all_triggers();
```

Comment: This is the second time this answer help me, I would +1 again if I could

Comment: `information_schema` is missing TRUNCATE triggers, so use something like this: `SELECT tgname AS trigger_name, relname AS event_object_table FROM pg_trigger INNER JOIN pg_class ON pg_class.oid = tgrelid`

Comment: I posted my own answer handling TRUNCATE triggers properly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57577258/644332

Comment: replace with `quote_ident(triggNameRecord.trigger_name)` and `quote_ident(triggTableRecord.event_object_table)` to properly quote any strings that are also keywords used by postgres

Answer (score 8):

I prefer this (based on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591113/drop-all-functions-from-postgres-database)) over the accepted answer by @kuznetso3v because it gives me a chance to inspect the `DROP STATEMENT`s before executing them with copy-paste:

```
SELECT 'DROP TRIGGER ' || trigger_name || ' ON ' || event_object_table || ';'
FROM information_schema.triggers
WHERE trigger_schema = 'public';
```

Comment: can we just remove the select to actually drop it

Answer (score 3):

Take a look in the information_schema:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.triggers;
```

Comment: SELECT trigger_name FROM information_schema.triggers; works better.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** See the real solution for the full function you want.

Alright, I came up with a function that does this for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION strip_all_triggers() RETURNS text AS $$ DECLARE
        triggNameRecord RECORD;
    triggTableRecord RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR triggNameRecord IN select distinct(trigger_name) from information_schema.triggers where trigger_schema = 'public' LOOP
        SELECT distinct(event_object_table) INTO triggTableRecord from information_schema.triggers where trigger_name = triggNameRecord.trigger_name;
        RAISE NOTICE 'Dropping trigger: % on table: %', triggNameRecord.trigger_name, triggTableRecord.event_object_table;
        EXECUTE 'DROP TRIGGER ' || triggNameRecord.trigger_name || ' ON ' || triggTableRecord.event_object_table || ';';
    END LOOP;

    RETURN 'done';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;

select strip_all_triggers();
```

That will drop any trigger in your public schema.

Answer (score 2):

Simply cascade drop the language in which you created the triggers.
For example, I create triggers in `plpgsql`, so the following query deletes all triggers instantaneously -

```
DROP LANGUAGE plpgsql CASCADE;
```

Comment: You seem like a high-stakes kind of guy

Comment: ERROR:  cannot drop language plpgsql because extension plpgsql requires it
HINT:  You can drop extension plpgsql instead.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest will be to `pg_dump -s` object definitions and filter it for lines starting with `CREATE TRIGGER`.

Something like

```
./pg_dump -s db_name | grep '^CREATE TRIGGER' | \
  while read _ _ triggername _; do \
    echo drop trigger "$triggername;"; \
  done
```

(in bash) should work (review it and then run in database).

But perhaps you should consider `alter table table_name disable trigger trigger_name` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I made two improvements of the solution from the older answers:

- added filtering by trigger name, table and schema
- properly handling "truncate" triggers (ignored by the original solution)

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION strip_all_triggers() RETURNS text AS $$ DECLARE
    triggRecord RECORD;
BEGIN
    create temp table all_triggers on commit drop as (
        SELECT tgname AS trigger_name, n.nspname as trigger_schema,  relname as trigger_table
        FROM pg_trigger
                 JOIN pg_class ON pg_class.oid = tgrelid
                 JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = pg_class.relnamespace);

    FOR triggRecord IN select distinct on (trigger_schema, trigger_table, trigger_name) trigger_schema, trigger_table, trigger_name from all_triggers
                       where trigger_schema like 'public' and trigger_name like '%' -- MY FILTER
        LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE 'Dropping trigger: % on table: %.%', triggRecord.trigger_name, triggRecord.trigger_schema, triggRecord.trigger_table;
            EXECUTE 'DROP TRIGGER ' || triggRecord.trigger_name || ' ON ' || triggRecord.trigger_schema || '.' || triggRecord.trigger_table || ';';
        END LOOP;

    RETURN 'done';
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;

select strip_all_triggers();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start from this query, to find outr trigger names:

```
select * from pg_trigger t,pg_proc where
 pg_proc.oid=t.tgfoid
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on Drux's response (Thanks!), I added the 'distinct' keyword to eliminate double statements that break bulk query runs.

```
SELECT distinct 'DROP TRIGGER ' || trigger_name || ' ON ' || event_object_table || ';'
FROM information_schema.triggers
WHERE trigger_schema = 'public';
```