# Drop all functions from Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a database with an old broken version of PostGIS installed in it. I would like to easily drop all functions in the database (they're all from PostGIS). Is there a simple way to do this? Even simply extracting a list of function names would be acceptable as I could just make a large `DROP FUNCTION` statement.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A [fine answer to this question can be found here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/74-How-to-delete-many-functions.html):

```
SELECT 'DROP FUNCTION ' || ns.nspname || '.' || proname 
       || '(' || oidvectortypes(proargtypes) || ');'
FROM pg_proc INNER JOIN pg_namespace ns ON (pg_proc.pronamespace = ns.oid)
WHERE ns.nspname = 'my_messed_up_schema'  order by proname;
```

Comment: Oftentimes, `ms.nspname = 'public'` applies.

Comment: The above SQL will fail on not lower case or not alphanumeric function/schema names. Better use quote_ident or format('DROP FUNCTION %I.%I(%s);', nspname, proname, oidvectortypes(proargtypes)) to get SQL identifiers quoted correctly.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, this doesn't actually drop the functions, just generates the drop commands to be run subsequently.  Bit of a gotcha :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just as there was a [`postgis.sql` enabler install script](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db), there is also an `uninstall_postgis.sql` uninstall script.

```
psql -d [yourdatabase] -f /path/to/uninstall_postgis.sql
```

Warning: Be prepared to see your geometry/geography columns and data disappear!